# How do I use an JSON file as an aray

Tags: python, arrays, json

Im trying to use a json file to use as an arya so on line itsnt extreemely long.

Code in Python I am using atm to try to read the JSON thing: (I found some other thing in another question and it got me this far)

```
import json

with open('rooms.json') as f:
    rooms = json.load(f)
```

The code in rooms.json:

```
[
// The Skeld 0-13
"Upper Engine", 
"Cafeteria", 
"Weapons",
"Reactor",
"Security",
"Medbay",
"O2",
"Navigation",
"Lower Engine",
"Electrical",
"Storage",
"Admin",
"Communications",
"Shields",

// Polus 14-29
"Northwest",
"Northeast",
"Laboratory",
"Security",
"Electrical",
"Storage",
"O2",
"Communications",
"Central",
"Office",
"East",
"Southwest",
"Weapons",
"South",
"Admin",
"Specimen Room",

//MIRA HQ 29-41
"Greenhouse",
"Office",
"Admin",
"Reactor",
"Laboratory",
"launchpad",
"Locker room",
"Communicatins",
"Medbay",
"torage",
"afeteria'"
"balcony"
]
```

The error i get (i use sublime btw and python 3.8.6):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\src\Python\AmongUs\AmongUs.py", line 7, in <module>
    rooms = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

Image of the thing in Python:
[image: Immage]

Comment: Unfortunately your `rooms.json` file is not `json`. Where did you get this file from? Can you persuade who ever produced it to produce valid `json`?

Comment: Are the names in the comments meant to group the lists below them?

Comment: @buran - that's potentially a great link but it depends on whether the information in the comments is something OP wants to keep. It could be that we have data for The Skeld, then for Polus, etc... OP doesn't seem to want to clarify that so we just have to wait.

Comment: @tdelaney, agree. Although, if that information is important, it really shouldn't be a comment

Comment: when i remove comment i still get error (changed some stuff too)
https://pastebin.com/GE7JmzbP

Comment: You have a different program there. Your code from your original post works when you remove the comments from `rooms.json`

Comment: i fixed it    ajsdhajkdhajkdhjkadhjkahdjkahdj

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`commentjson`](https://commentjson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module to parse json with embedded comments.

```
pip install commentjson
```

Note:: Your string has invalid json *even if you ignore the comments!*
In the very end:

> "torage",
> "afeteria**'**"**,**
> "balcony"
> ]

There's an extra apostrophe in "afeteria'" that isn't escaped, and a missing comma at the end of the same line.

```
import commentjson as jsonc

jsonc_string = """[
// The Skeld 0-13
"Upper Engine", 
"Cafeteria", 
"Weapons",
"Reactor",
"Security",
"Medbay",
"O2",
"Navigation",
"Lower Engine",
"Electrical",
"Storage",
"Admin",
"Communications",
"Shields",

// Polus 14-29
"Northwest",
"Northeast",
"Laboratory",
"Security",
"Electrical",
"Storage",
"O2",
"Communications",
"Central",
"Office",
"East",
"Southwest",
"Weapons",
"South",
"Admin",
"Specimen Room",

//MIRA HQ 29-41
"Greenhouse",
"Office",
"Admin",
"Reactor",
"Laboratory",
"launchpad",
"Locker room",
"Communicatins",
"Medbay",
"torage",
"Cafeteria",
"balcony"
]"""

lst = jsonc.loads(jsonc_string)
```

And this gives us the parsed list:

```
print(lst)
# Output: 
# ['Upper Engine', 'Cafeteria', 'Weapons', 'Reactor', 'Security', 'Medbay', 'O2', 'Navigation', 'Lower Engine', 'Electrical', 'Storage', 'Admin', 'Communications', 'Shields', 'Northwest', 'Northeast', 'Laboratory', 'Security', 'Electrical', 'Storage', 'O2', 'Communications', 'Central', 'Office', 'East', 'Southwest', 'Weapons', 'South', 'Admin', 'Specimen Room', 'Greenhouse', 'Office', 'Admin', 'Reactor', 'Laboratory', 'launchpad', 'Locker room', 'Communicatins', 'Medbay', 'torage', 'Cafeteria', 'balcony']
```

Comment: If you're going to use a third-party module to enable comments in json, why not use yaml?

Comment: @kojiro Because yaml also reads in the comments as elements of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that JSON does not support comments

```
$ python -c 'import json; json.loads("""[
> // here is a comment
> "some string"]""")'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/michaelsmith/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/michaelsmith/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/michaelsmith/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

You either must remove the comments and produce valid json, or use a format that does support comments. Since YAML is a superset of json, you could parse these files as yaml, only changing the comments to start with `#` instead of `//`.

Other formats that support comments are ini (via python's configparser module) and toml.

Comment: I removed the comments but i got this error     kojiro

https://pastebin.com/BsbxQAs6

Comment: @Martin It seems to me that the error there is very clear.

Comment: I fixed it asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd